# What does "in practice" mean here?

Tags: support, api-v2.2, documentation

From [`/answers/{id}/delete`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/delete-answer):

> **In practice**, this method will never return an object.

For me, "in practice" means that the method will *maybe* return an object. But why? That's not good from an application developer's point of view. Either the method returns an object, or not, there should no in-between in my opinion. That's just a pain to test each time if an object is received, or not.

Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Near as I can tell, **that particular doc page doesn't work at all.** Plugged in valid values and no results, nor errors, were issued.  The route works as expected from my own app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, that line is incorrect.  **The method will *always* return a JSON object** (barring certain server failures).

But the `items` array will be empty or missing.

**On success**, the default object looks like:

```js
{
    items: [],
    has_more: false,
    quota_max: 10000,
    quota_remaining: 9998
}
```

And **on (normal) failure**, it looks like:

```js
{
    error_id: 407,
    error_message: "Answer not found",
    error_name: "write_failed"
}
//or
{
    error_id: 407,
    error_message: "Only answer owners can delete their answers with this method",
    error_name: "write_failed"
}
//or
{
    error_id: 403,
    error_message: "Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write",
    error_name: "access_denied"
}
// etc., etc.
```

Comment: So basically, the "in practice" is misleading here.

Comment: Yeah, a little.  I imagine that whoever wrote it was just less precise than I would prefer, and perhaps rushed.